# How to get a list of all the brands of my product entity?

Tags: php, symfony, filter, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am new to both Symfony and API platform and trying to understand how to get all unique brands and product types of my products in a list so that I can use them later to display a list of filters to use in my frontend.

I'm a bit lost as to how to do this. I want to have a custom endpoint products/filters that would return me the list.

I would like to have it in this form:

```
{
brands: [
    "Agilent",
    "Comtr"
    "Anot
    ],
types:[
     "Accelerometer",
     "Sonometer",
     "Micro-amplifier"
]
}
```

Both brand and type are nested properties of my entity Product, they come from my entity ProductModel. I am using Api platform for my api that is why there is a lot of annotations.

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProductModel::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $idProductModel;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The field serial number is mandatory.")
     */
    private $serialNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"product_get"})
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"product_get"})
     *
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The field confidential is mandatory.")
     *
     */
    private $confidential;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Storage::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $idStorage;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $idUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"product_get"})
     */
    private $idUserDelete;

    /**
     * Many products can have many products
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="myProducts")
     */
    private $partOfthisProduct;

    /**
     * Many products can have many products
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="partOfthisProduct")
     * @JoinTable(name="product_has_product",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="related_product_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $myProducts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Sensor::class, mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"product_get", "product_list"})
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $sensors;
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use App\Repository\ProductModelRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductModelRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={"get"},
 *     collectionOperations={"get"},
 *     normalizationContext={
 *     "groups"={"read"}}
 * )
 */
class ProductModel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read", "product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Groups({"read", "product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $modelName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProductType::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read", "product_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $idProductType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Unit::class)
     */
    private $idInputUnit;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Unit::class)
     */
    private $idOutputUnit;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Brand::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get", "product_list"})
     */
    private $idBrand;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=TestType::class)
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get",  "product_get"})
     */
    private $idTestsTypes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get"})
     */
    private $periodicity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get", "product_get"})
     */
    private $nominalSensitivity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TestType::class)
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get",  "product_get"})
     */
    private $periodicityTest;


    /**
     * Many ProductModel have Many SensorModel.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="SensorModel")
     * @JoinTable(name="productModel_sensorModels",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Product_model_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Sensor_Model_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     * @Groups({"read", "sensor_get",  "product_get"})
     */
    private $sensorModels;
```

What would be the way to do this ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Think the best way to do it is with a custom action that calls a method from the entity's repository.

First you add a custom operation to your @ApiResource definition, in the collectionOperations part in this case.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={"get","put","delete"},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get","post",
 *          "types"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/product_models/brands",
 *             "controller"=DistinctBrandsAction::class,
 *             "openapi_context"={
 *                 "parameters"={}
 *             },
 *             "read"=false,
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=Repository::class)
 */
```

Then you add a method to your entity's repository (it would be ProductModelRepository in your case).

This method will query the collection and get the distinct values of the desired column. You'll have to modify this a bit to get the exact output you want (add the product types etc.):

```
//..blah blah.. use statements etc.

class ProductModelRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Report::class);
    }

    //this is the method you're adding:
    //for symfony 3+ you use groupBy() instead of distinct() to get distinct values for a column
    public function getDistinctBrands() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->select('r.idBrand')
            ->groupBy('r.idBrand')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a controller for your configured action that calls the method you added to the repository and then outputs it. (This would go in src/Controller/Action/DistinctBrandsAction.php if you're using autowiring)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Action;

use App\Entity\Report;
use App\Repository\ProductModelRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * Class DistinctBrandsAction
 */
final class DistinctBrandsAction extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @param ProductModelRepository $productRepository
     * @return Array
     */
    public function __invoke(ProductModelRepository $productRepository): Array
    {
        return $productRepository->getDistinctBrands();
    }
}
```

You can use the console to see what your resulting route is. It should be grouped with your ProductModel routes when running `php bin/console debug:router`

Further reading:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#custom-controller-action